# Unit test Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a mistake? I don't understand why it's not working.

```
class Form:

    def __init__(self, name, pas, email='', link=''):
        self.name = name
        self.pas = pas
        self.email = email
        self.link = link

form = Form("Mam", "testpas")
form2 = Form("Dad", "testpas2", "ex@gma.co", "https://https://stackoverflow.com/")
print(form_url("https://itproger.com"))
```

Unit test code:

```
import unittest
import form

class TestForm(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.obj = form.Form()

    def test_init(self):

        self.assertEqual(self.obj.name, "Mam")
        self.assertEqual(self.obj.pas, "testpas")

        self.assertEqual(self.obj.name, "Dad")
        self.assertEqual(self.obj.pas, "testpas2")
        self.assertEqual(self.obj.email, "ex@gma.co")
        self.assertEqual(self.obj.link, "https://https://stackoverflow.com/")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: How do you know that there is a mistake? Is there an error reported somewhere? Can you share it with us?

Comment: FAILED (errors=1)
True

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:****************\test_example.py", line 9, in setUp
    self.obj = form.Form()
TypeError: Form.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'pas'

Comment: Why do you think this should work when you are instantiating a `Form` without the required parameters?

Comment: I import 
form.py       
form = Form("Mam", "testpas")
form2 = Form("Dad", "testpas2", "ex@gma.co", "https://https://stackoverflow.com/")   and 
def setUp(self):
        self.obj = form.Form()

Comment: That's why im here to get unswer !

Comment: I can see that from your code. Why do you do that? Did you mean: `self.obj = form.form`?

Comment: I want to get data from form and form2 inside in unitest. With  def setUp(self):

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many mistakes here, but I'll try to start you in the right direction.

```py
class TestForm(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.obj1 = form.form
        self.obj2 = form.form2
```

Comment: Yes i found some mistakes. Thank you also for direction. I just started learn Python and for shure sorry. I get your message from previous comment about the rules. I note it already form myself.

Comment: Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\test_example.py", line 8, in setUp
    self.obj1 = form.form
AttributeError: 'Form' object has no attribute 'form' 

Truing to read about atributeError.  But didnt get.

Comment: That's a different error. You will only get that with code that is different to what you have posted.